# iOS UIDatePicker display without time

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I would like to have a Date Picker with only one wheel, filled with days as on the Date and Time mode.

[image]

If I choose the Date mode, I have 3 wheels and I loose the name of the day.
In fact I would like something like the date and time mode, but only with the date.

I could use a UIPickerView, but I would have to fill it by myself with a very big array of data, as I want to be able go back far in time. With the Date picker, it's filled automatically, which is cool.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: you only want to show the green box contents?

Comment: Yes Omkar, that's it

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **UIDatePicker**'s **pickerMode** property to do that.

```
datePicker.pickerMode = .Date
```

Look into header file, you will see that there are few other Options that you can play with. Other values are;

```
 Time
 Date
 DateAndTime
 CountDownTimer
```

Comment: I checked all these, they don't correspond to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the UIPickerView instead of the UIDatePicker. There is no possibility to customise UIDatePicker in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

try displayedComponents with .date

```
DatePicker( selection: .constant(futureDate), displayedComponents: [.date],
                        label: { Text("Due date") })
```

Answer (score -1):

As you only need to show the contents that you have marked in the green box. You can use this https://github.com/attias/AADatePicker and modify it a bit and you can get it as per your requirement.

The changes you will need to make are within the AADatePickerView Class

1) In viewForRow method comment the following things
[image]

2) Second change 
[image]
[image]

Comment: commenting out the code i mentioned is a quick fix for your solution , you can completely remove the second  and third component from the picker view to make it proper.

Comment: @Eric is that what you need ?

Comment: Great, thanks for this solution, I put in place asap :)

Answer (score -2):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
        let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        print(selectedDate)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.